# How to distinguish between carbon-carbon double bond lengths?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, hydrocarbons

> Which of the following compounds should have the longest carbon-carbon double bond?
>
> 1. $\ce{CH2=C=CH2}$
> 2. $\ce{H3C-CH=CH2}$
> 3. $\ce{(H3C)3-C-CH=CH2}$
> 4. $\ce{(H3C)2C=CH2}$

I know that single bond > double > triple length-wise, but how do you distinguish between double bonds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can draw hyperconjugation structures to compare bond length. The more α-hydrogens the alkene has, the more hyperconjugation structures it has, and the higher is the degree of delocalization of the π-bond and therefore the longer is the bond. When double bond character decreases, bond length increases. Therefore the answer should be (d).